# how to count the frequency of a specific word(not the string) regardless of preceding strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose that this is the dataset that I am working on:

`df1 = pd.DataFrame(['you youe', 'you You YOU', 'eyou Young'], columns=['words'])`

`print(df1)`

[image]

I am hoping to count the frequency of strings 'you' and 'your' as words, regardless of what precedes or follows these strings and regardless the lower or upper cases.

I have put strings like 'youe' to test that my code doesn't miscount it.

this is what I have tried so far:

`df1['counts']=df1['words'].str.count(' you|you. |you, |you | You | YOU|YOU. |YOU, |YOU|YOU | your|your | Your|Your | YOUR|YOUR ')`

`print(df1)`

The expected output would be:

```
        words      count 

  0      you youe    1

  1   you You YOU    3

  2    eyou Young    0
```

But I am getting:

```
        words      count 

  0      you youe    1

  1   you You YOU    2

  2    eyou Young    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use words boundaries by `\b\b` with optionaly match `r`, for not case sensitive test is possible add `re.I` flag:

```
import re

df1['new'] = df1['words'].str.count(r'\b(you[r]*)\b', flags=re.I)
print (df1)
          words  new
0      you youe    1
1  you Your YOU    3
2    eyou Young    0
```

Comment: This works really well for dataframe, but I was trying to use .count(r'\b(you[r]*)\b', flags=re.I) to a single string i get : 'count() takes no keyword arguments'.  really need your guidance again.

Comment: @deLaJU  - use `a = 'you youe'` and `out = pd.Series([a]).str.count(r'\b(you[r]*)\b', flags=re.I).iat[0]`